# Bitwise XOR return value used incorrectly?

Tags: java, netbeans-7, swap, bitwise-xor

I swapped the values of two integers with a XOR-swap, and for this I used the following line of code:

```
a ^= (b ^= (a ^= b));
```

Afterwards, `b` gets the correct value (the former value of `a`), but `a` becomes zero. If I don't write it on one line it works fine, like this:

```
a ^= b;
b ^= a;
a ^= b;
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is netbeans/compiler/JRE doing something wrong? (using netbeans 7.2.1)